# custom header UIView to all the VC?

Tags: ios, uiview, custom-view, swift5

I am trying to create a custom header file to all the **ViewControllers** in project. The following image is an actual design.

[image: Actual design]

So that I am trying to create Custom view with Xib file as below :

```
import UIKit

class HamburgrView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // 1. setup any properties here
        // 2. call super.init(frame:)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }
    override open func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        xibSetup()
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {

    }
    func xibSetup() {

       let  tempView = loadViewFromNib()
        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        tempView.frame = bounds
        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        tempView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(tempView)

    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of:self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "HamburgrView", bundle: bundle)

        // Assumes UIView is top level and only object in CustomView.xib file
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }


}
```

We don't know how to draw that Hamburger menu icon with curve and its start position from **SafeArealayoutGuide**.

I trying one view with x position negative -40 and giving cornerRadius not coming perfect curve like above image.

Output look not good.

[image]

My **ViewController** Code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let hamView = HamburgrView(frame: .zero)
        self.view.addSubview(hamView)
        hamView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hamView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            hamView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            hamView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
            hamView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  80)
            ])
    }
```

As @sandip answer I have changed like below :

```
func xibSetup() {

       let  tempView = loadViewFromNib()
        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        tempView.frame = bounds
        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        tempView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(tempView)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.center.y), radius: 50, startAngle: -1.5708, endAngle: 1.5708, clockwise: true).cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```

Output Looks Below :

[image: Image Ouput after adding **CAShapeLayer**]
Any idea would be appreciate.

Comment: You can use image/icons.

Comment: anyother way programmatically, I trying one view with x position negative -40 and giving cornerRadius not coming perfect curve like above image

Comment: Are you struggling in white curve or in creating 3 horizontal lines?

Comment: white curve creation with menu icon

Comment: So whole thing (*Menu button, title label, profile button*) in UINavigationBar or you have your own VIEW/XIB ?

Comment: Own View would better...U check updated question... Can you share your mail id or Skype I will share my sample project.

Comment: Ok, Is this is the static bar in all the screens or it will keep changing? You might need back button also.

Comment: static bar only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

You can easily achieve it with `CAShapeLayer` and `UIBezierPath`

```
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.center.y), radius: 30, startAngle: -1.5708, endAngle: 1.5708, clockwise: true).cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

In your code change arc centre as x to be zero and y to hamburger view's vertical centre and add it to `self.view`

Hope it helps

**EDIT 1:**

As OP has asked for complete code in comment updating the answer

```
class HamburgrView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // 1. setup any properties here
        // 2. call super.init(frame:)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }
    override open func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        xibSetup()
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {

    }
    func xibSetup() {

       let  tempView = loadViewFromNib()
        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        tempView.frame = bounds
        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        tempView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(tempView)

    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of:self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "HamburgrView", bundle: bundle)

        // Assumes UIView is top level and only object in CustomView.xib file
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 40), radius: 50, startAngle: -1.5708, endAngle: 1.5708, clockwise: true).cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Reason OPs arc coming outside hamburger view is because of wrong arc centre

changing to `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 40)` from `self.view.center.y` should solve the issue. Updated the code to reflect the same

**Why 40?**

Because OP is setting height of hamburger view to 80. So 80/2 = 40

**Why cant we use `bounds.size.height / 2` or `self.view.center.y`?**

because in didMoveToSuperview OP's constraint has not kicked in yet so it is taking the height view in xib which I don't think is 80 so it sets the arc centre with that value but then your constraint changes height to 80.

Here is final O/P:

[image]

Comment: Where should I have to add this code Controller file or Hamburger View File? Check my Controller file code in question

Comment: @karthikeyan : Hamburger file. Its better if you call this function in either `didMoveToSuperview` `willMove(toSuperview` or `willMove(toWindow` to ensure your view's frame is rendered before you actually call core graphics APIs

Comment: I am using your code after xib loaded, but output not correct..What is start angle and End angle

Comment: func xibSetup() {
       let  tempView = loadViewFromNib()
        tempView.frame = bounds
        tempView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(tempView)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.center.y), radius: 50, startAngle: -1.5708, endAngle: 1.5708, clockwise: true).cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

Comment: @karthikeyan: I told you to call this function in `didMoveToSuperview` not in xibsetup, your xibsetup is called in init when your view is not even rendered so its frame is also not set, its way too early

Comment: start angle is -90 and end angle is 90 in radians

Comment: @karthikeyan: Use `HamburgrView` code I have added. Check `didMoveToSuperview` usage

Comment: Even now Output coming like added above image

Comment: @karthikeyan: K lemme check

Comment: @karthikeyan: updated the code, use `HamburgrView` code now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201930/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-karthikeyan).